# Error al actualizar datos mysql con update en php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código para actualizar los datos del usuario. He editado el código, el error viene de las sentencias sql, me dan error de página, debe haber algun error de comillas que no entiendo.
Este es el código:

```
   <?php
include 'include_sesions.php';

if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) { // <= false
    $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET Nombre_user='$_POST[first_name]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
if (isset($_POST['last_name'])) { // <= false
    $sql1 = "UPDATE usuario SET Apellido_user='$_POST[last_name]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $conexion->query($sql1);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
if (isset($_POST['provincia'])) { // <= false
    $sql2 = "UPDATE usuario SET Provicncia_user='$_POST[provincia]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $conexion->query($sql2);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
if (isset($_POST['cp'])) { // <= false
    $sql3 = "UPDATE usuario SET CP_user='$_POST[cp]' where Correo_user='$email'";
    $conexion->query($sql3);
    // No está vacía (true)
}
$extensiones = array(0=>'image/jpg',1=>'image/jpeg',2=>'image/png');
$max_tamanyo = 1024 * 1024 * 8;

$ruta_fichero_origen = $_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name'];
$ruta_nuevo_destino = '../img/Img_profile/' . $_FILES['imagen1']['name'];
if ( in_array($_FILES['imagen1']['type'], $extensiones) ) {
     if ( $_FILES['imagen1']['size']< $max_tamanyo ) {
         if($row['Img_user']!=NULL){
            unlink("../img/Img_profile/".$row['Img_user']);
         }
          if( move_uploaded_file ( $ruta_fichero_origen, $ruta_nuevo_destino ) ) {
               header('Location: panel-control.php');//redirecciona a la pagina del usuario
          }
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: Existen varias actualizaciones independientes, puedes indicar cuales de ellas no se actualiza y si recibes algun tipo de mensaje de error?

Comment: no recibo ningun mensaje de error y no se actualiza ninguna

Comment: Verifica que la variable $email se encuentre definida, en cada sentencia SQL cuando recibes por POST debe de ir entrecomillado.

Comment: Saludos. La variable `$email` no hay referencia donde la inicias. Estas usando `mysqli_query` (le falta un parámetro) y `$conexion->query` verifica las consideraciones para cada una (https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) homologa como enviaras los SQL a la BD; si aún así sigues mal revisa https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php si el error fuese en el SQL o hacia tu BD.

Comment: Si esta entrando a los ifs? Cuando uso POST yo uso ISSET() en lugar de empty()

Comment: he cambiado a isser y he descubierto que el error esta en las sentencias sql, parece que algo esta mal escrito aunque no veo el que. la variable $email esta declarada en el include sesion.php

Comment: Voto cierre por pregunta duplicada (y respondida): [Error de escritura en sentencia UPDATE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386157/error-de-escritura-en-sentencia-update)